# maven-jaxb-plugin

Tags: maven, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am using this plugin to generate java source from XSD.It is generating fine.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xjc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                   </executions>


          </plugin>
```

but in one of java files import i can see below import but it is not generating namespace like below

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AccountBaseType", namespace = "http://services.com/11/basetypes/account", propOrder = {
    "accountId",
    "accountSummary"
})
```

i am getting this thing

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AccountBaseType", propOrder = {
    "accountId",
    "accountSummary"
```

Comment: Without seeing the relevant part of your XSD this is rather difficult to answer.

Comment: same schema file when i build with ant it will generated namespace prefix so basically i want to generate namespace = "http://services.com/11/basetypes/account", this thing in my .java file